# How to implement add function for immutable doubly linked list?

Tags: ocaml

This question has theoretical motivation only (of course, there are multiple ways to avoid it in real-life development).

Let's introduce an immutable doubly linked list as the following OCaml type.

```
type t =
  | Link of 
     { value : int; 
        next : t; 
        prev : t 
     }
  | End
```

We can easily make an instance with three elements within recursive definitions of (non-functional) values that OCaml allows:

```
let _123 = 
  let rec a = Link { value = 1; next = b; prev = End }
  and     b = Link { value = 2; next = c; prev = a   }
  and     c = Link { value = 3; next = End; prev = b } in
  a
```

We can represent '_123' with the following image:

[image]

That's fine, but it's like nothing without the ability to create lists dynamically (with any amount of items). So, I declared the function:

```
let add x = function
  | End       -> Link { value = x; next = End; prev = End }
  | Link tail -> let rec head = Link { value = x; next = tail'; prev = End }
                 and tail' = Link { tail with prev = head } in
                 head
```

and tried to use it:

```
let _123 = 
  End |> add 3 
      |> add 2 
      |> add 1
```

the result isn't what I expected:
[image]
[image]

It contains extra items and corrupted links. I understand why it is so. It is impossible to create a new version of the list based on the "tail" because of producing extra items. It looks like there is only one way to do that - it is to recreate the list from scratch for every newly added item. Ok. But how to do that? How to implement an add function for the immutable doubly linked list?

Comment: The question you may want to ask is, if _every_ node has to change on _any_ insert, what problem does this data structure solve? If you're trying to make singly linked lists "better" you may first wish to research [zippers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)).

Comment: @Chris I have started my question description with the remark that it is a theoretical question. Of course, using a doubly linked list in pure functional programming is doubtful. I am researching OCaml language abilities and trying to understand the frame of recursive (non-functional) values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable doubly-linked list cannot be created incrementally.
Consider the single-list element list:

```ml
let singleton value = Link { value; next = End; prev = End }
```

Since the prev element of this list is `End`, it cannot be the part of any list with more than one element. The same issue exists with list of length n: such list does not contain any sublist which is a list of length k < n.

In other words to create a list with n elements, one need to create `n` link of the list simultaneously, which is not possible without mutation. In particular, mutually recursive definitions are implemented using a single mutation initialization under the hood.

But this also means, that if we accept this constraint, we can have doubly-link persistent list by using observably-invisible mutations:

```ml
type 'a l =
  | End
  | Link of { prev: 'a l; value:'a; next: unit -> 'a l }
```

Here, replacing the type of next by `unit -> 'a l` gives us just enough breathing room to create the list step by step:

```
let create l =
  (* precondition: when [create ref_to_prev q] is called [!ref_to_prev ()] will
     be a valid link *)
  let rec create ref_to_prev q () =
    match q with
    | [] -> End
    | value :: q ->
      (* dummy value *)
      let future_self = ref (fun () -> raise Non_initialized) in
      (* next cannot be called yet, but it has not been published yet,
         thus this is fine *)
      let next () = create future_self q in
      let self = Link {
        prev = (* precondition: this is now a valid value *)
          !ref_to_prev ();
        value;
        next;
      } in
      (* we backpatch the [prev] argument for [next], now that we have a [self] link *)
      future_self := (fun () -> self);
      (* [next] can now be called, and [self] is a valid link
         that we can publish to the outside world *)
      self
  in
  create (ref (Fun.const End)) l ()
```

Here, create has the expected type `'a list -> 'a l`. We can check that we have the right digraph structure with

```ml
let rec backward_list = function
  | End -> []
  | Link l ->
    l.value :: backward_list l.prev


let rec forth_and_back = function
  | End -> []
  | Link lk as l ->
    match lk.next () with
    | End -> backward_list l
    | l ->  lk.value :: forth_and_back l

let test = forth_and_back (create [1;2;3;4])
```

which returns `[1;2;3;4;3;2;1]` as expected.

We have us a persistent doubly-linked list: no mutation can be observed from the outside but the elements of the list are in fact stored in the thunk:

```ml
let next () = create future_self q in
```

and we constructing the next element of the list on the fly whenever we call
the `next` field.
We could build the list once, by replacing

```ml
  next: unit -> 'a l;
```

by

```ml
  next: 'a l Lazy.t;
```

in the definition of the type constructor `'a l`.